# Is it possible to change HTML "value" for a django rendered form field?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Basically, I have a form with a radio select widget for a field called `Queue`. `Queue` has 4 choices, which are coming from a `model`, accessed and set via `views.py`. I am rendering this form on my template by doing `{{form.queue.0}}`, `{{form.queue.1}}` and so on.

For example, `{{form.queue.3}}` gives me:

```
<input id="id_queue_3" name="queue" value="2" type="radio">
```

As you can see, there is a value and field index mismatch - `queue.3` is showing up as `value="2"` and this is messing with some JS that uses the value to open the right subset of menus under each radio button.

Is it possible for me to render the radio field on the template by manually specifying the `value`?

My `forms.py`:

```
class PublicTicketForm():
     queue = forms.ChoiceField(
            widget=forms.RadioSelect(),  
            label=_('What do you need help with?'),    
            required=True,
            choices=()
        )
```

My `views.py` for this form:

```
form = PublicTicketForm(initial=initial_data)
        form.fields['queue'].choices = [('', 'Other')] + [
            (q.id, q.title) for q in Queue.objects.filter(allow_public_submission=True)]
```

Comment: What value(instead of 2) do you want to give to the HTML's value attribute in this input tag:  "<input id="id_queue_3" name="queue" value="2" type="radio">"  ?

Comment: Let's say 3, because it's third in list

Comment: Check the answer I've posted. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your code:

```
form = PublicTicketForm(initial=initial_data)
    form.fields['queue'].choices = [('', 'Other')] + [
        ((int(q.id)+1), q.title) for q in Queue.objects.filter(allow_public_submission=True)]
```

**Note:** I assumed that you wanted a constant change(increment of 1) in the `value` attribute of your `<input>` tag.

For example:

```
<input id="id_queue_3" name="queue" value="2" type="radio">
<input id="id_queue_4" name="queue" value="3" type="radio">
```

becomes

```
<input id="id_queue_3" name="queue" value="3" type="radio">
<input id="id_queue_4" name="queue" value="4" type="radio">
```

**To elaborate this:** in the code snippet:

```
queue = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(),  
        label=_('What do you need help with?'),    
        required=True,
        choices=()
    )
```

the attribute `choices` takes a simple tuple structured like:

```
(('I_become_the_value_1' , 'I_appear_on_browser_screen_1'),
('I_become_the_value_2' , 'I_appear_on_browser_screen_2'),
#and so on...
)
```

So when you are supplying the pk(*q.id is the pk value of a model*) as the first index of the tuple, the pk value actually becomes the `value` attribute in `<input>` tag.

**Note:** You should always know that this `value` attribute in `<input>` tag in the backbone structure of the ChoiceField in Django. It helps in mapping what value was selected by the user.

**Lastly**, make sure that you successfully retrieve the exact value selected by the user when the form is submitted by cross-checking them. You might need a tweak there as well. **There is a possibility that choices selected by the user in the browser aren't received correctly inside your view.(pk values might get mixed up)**

**EDIT:** As asked, I too feel that using increments in pk is not a very good solution. To avoid this, you can declare your own primary key field through **UUIDField**. Read about it [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) This will allow you to get a large string(unique) in the `value` attribute of `<input>` tag. Use it like:

Inside your models.py:

```
class Queue(models.Model):
    #all your fields.
    alternative_unique_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    #Rest of the code.
```

Now you can query it in the same way but add *alternative_unique_field* as the first index of the tuple.

in your views.py

```
form = PublicTicketForm(initial=initial_data)
form.fields['queue'].choices = [('', 'Other')] + [
    (q.alternative_unique_id, q.title) for q in Queue.objects.filter(allow_public_submission=True)]
```

Also, you can declare this alternative_unique_id as a primary key as well.
That will save some space in the database.

**Second Approach:** instead of using a UUIDField, you could create your own primary key field by simply setting `primary_key=True` inside the field. You can do it like:

```
name = models.CharField(primary_key = True , max_length = 64)
```

**But make sure** it's always going to be unique and change some logic in your `form.fields['queue'].choices` to get a suitable value inside the `value` attribute of the `<input>` tag.

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but as you said, the "value" is coming from the pk field of the model and I think it auto increments. The problem with adding 1 would be that it would screw things over when we remove or add new objects to these models. Is there something I can do set the "value" tag to another unique field perhaps and the modify my views to check for name instead of value?

Comment: @Di437 I suppose there could be one. Please wait while I update my answer.